# how to replace/update whole documents of particuar mongodb collection in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, updates

how to **replace/update whole documents** of particuar mongodb collection

eg: the process of save data in mongodb; call the api , the api get data from my website & save in mongodb.

for the **first** time I am calling the api, it gets data(**5 items of places**) from my website & should save in mongodb & collection length is 5 items.

after when I calling **second** time to the api, it gets data(now I am getting **17 items of places**) the mongodb collections **whole length should be 17**(**I am no need first api call data as 5 items of places** & needs to remove those data)

I am using schema to figure out the data.
how to implement above case,

Answer (score 0):

```
Although its not a good practice.But if you don't need you can remove all the existing documents before inserting new ones.
Try using remove query of mongodb.
```

Reference -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#mongodb-method-db.collection.remove

Comment: If its correct do upvote and mark as correct. Thank You